# Асинхронная инициализация свойств + Lazy

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, lazyloading

В классе ViewModel имеется два булевых свойства, на которые происходит Binding из xaml:

```
public bool CanPublish => Document.State.CanPublish();
public bool CanCreateToolData => Document.State.CanCreateToolData();
```

Разметка из xaml:

```
Visibility="{Binding CanCreateToolData, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
Visibility="{Binding CanPublish, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Поскольку вычисление статусов достаточно долгий процесс, то у меня в модели внутри методов CanPublish() и CanCreateToolData() используется инициализация некоторых полей через Lazy. Дебаггер показывает следующее:

1) Идём инициализировать свойство CanPublish, натыкаемся на Lazy;

2) Пока Lazy-метод выполняется, начинается инициализация второго свойства CanCreateToolData, которое тоже обращается к тому же самому Lazy-методу. В итоге:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Сообщение = ValueFactory пытается получить доступ к свойству Value этого экземпляра.
Источник = mscorlib
Трассировка стека:
 в System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
 в System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
 в System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
 в "путь к моему классу"
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: почему инициализация свойств производится асинхронно? Это из-за Lazy-методов? Ошибка, как я понимаю, заключается в том, что идёт обращение к одному и тому же Lazy-методу повторно, пока он ещё не закончил своё выполнение. Есть ли возможность как-то явно указать, что эти свойства должны инициализироваться синхронно?

Спасибо за внимание.

Дополню код Lazy-методом:
Тут обращение к свойству ClassConfig

```
    public bool CanCreateToolData()
    {
        ..
        if (ver.Services.Interpretator.ClassConfig == null) { return false; }
        ...
    }

    public bool CanPublish()
    {
        ..
        if (ver.Services.Interpretator.ClassConfig == null) { return false; }
        ...
    }
```

А тут вызов метода Lazy:

```
// поле класса, InvalidOperationException происходит при обращении к mClassDefiner.Value
public IClassDefiner ClassConfig => mClassDefiner.Value;

public Interpretator()
{    
    mClassDefiner = new Lazy<IClassDefiner>(GetClassDefiner);
}


private IClassDefiner GetClassDefiner()
{
  // ресурсоёмкая операция
}
```

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про код, который не показываете. Я не вижу в вашем коде Lazy метода.

Comment: @tym32167, добавил недостающий код, правда детали самого метода в данной ситуации не важны, Exception вылетает при повторном обращении к  mClassDefiner.Value до того, как он завершил свою работу (если я верно всё понимаю)

Comment: Вот смотрите - я хочу вам помочь, но код, который вы показываете, не компилируется. А даже если бы компилировался, то он ничего бы не воспроизвел. То есть вы по сути просите вам погадать на кусках кода, которые отношения не имеют к проблеме. Хорошо, я побуду местным телепатом - скорее всего у вас внутри метода с ресурсоёмкой операцией возникает исключение, потому все падает. Оберните его в try-catch и проверьте.  А если говорить про Lazy - то это потокобезопасный тип (если вы в конструктор false не передали) и я сомневаюсь, что он будет метод 2 раза вызывать.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо за стремление помочь. Дело в том, что  в Lazy-методе много специфического кода, который не имеет никакого отношения к данном проблеме, поскольку проблема исчезает при замене Lazy на обычные геттеры. Внутри этого метода имеется try-catch и исключений там нет.

Comment: @tym32167, постараюсь объяснить, как я понимаю данную ситуацию: идёт первое обращение к Lazy-полю, он идёт вычисляться, в это время происходит второе обращение к Lazy-полю, но природа Lazy такова, что он кеширует результат и при втором обращении уже выдает его без повторного вычисления. Но поскольку вычислиться оно ещё не успело - ловим эксепшн. Во время второго обращения к нему Value равен null, флаг IsValueCreated является false. Кстати, флаг IsValueFaulted = true. Поправьте, если я что-то не так понимаю

Comment: @tym32167, вы верно заметили, что Lazy потокобезопасен. Именно поэтому я изначально и поставил вопрос, есть ли возможность инициализировать свойства, к который происходит Binding, синхронно. Второе начинает инициализироваться до того, пока первое закончило инициализацию.

Comment: Не совсем так. В моем понимании - при первом обращении к Lazy начинает считаться результат. При повторном обращении - если результат ещё не посчитан, то вызов блокируется до получения результата. Я могу пример написать и продемонстрировать это, но для этого надо ответ уже писать, в комментарий такое  не поместится. По сути, Lazy - это аналог блокировки с двойной проверкой - потому оно без проблем справится с ситуацией, если вы пробуете получить ещё не посчитанный результат хоть с 10 потоков. Потому ищите проблемы в вашем коде. что вы не показываете.

Comment: Если в вашем случае `IsValueFaulted = true` то очевидно, при создании что то пошло не так, потому, как я уже написал, ищите проблему в коде создания

Comment: @tym32167, уверяю вас, никакой ошибки далее нет, поскольку запустив этот же код с байндингом к одному свойству, всё работает верно. Мне кажется, вы ошибаетесь по поводу того, что вызов блокируется при повторном обращении. При обращении второго потока, Lazy думает, что произошло рекурсивное обращение к Value и бросает исключение. Смотрите по ссылке https://github.com/elmah/Bootstrapper/issues/5

Comment: ваша ссылка к проблеме никак не относится. Вы рекурсивно пытаетесь получить значение - в коде, который не показали. В этом проблема.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим пример:

Есть класс с Lazy полем

```
public class Foo
{
    public Lazy<int> Lazy = new Lazy<int>(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - LAZY ENTER");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - LAZY EXIT");

        return 10;
    });
}
```

Мы логгируем входы и выходы из функции создания для поля. 
Далее, запустим параллельно 10 тредов и попробуем обратиться к нашему полю

```
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - START");

var target = new Foo();
var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x =>
{
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - TASK {x} ENTER");
        var value = target.Lazy.Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - TASK {x} EXIT");
    });
    thread.Start();
    return thread;
}).ToArray();

foreach (var t in threads) t.Join();

Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - END");
```

Вывод в консоль предсказуем: все треды ждут функцию сооздания, и после этого завершаются без исключений

```
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 33 - START
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 32 - TASK 0 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 31 - TASK 1 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 32 - LAZY ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 30 - TASK 2 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 29 - TASK 3 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 28 - TASK 4 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 27 - TASK 5 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 26 - TASK 6 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 25 - TASK 7 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 19 - TASK 8 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:05:55 - 18 - TASK 9 ENTER
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 32 - LAZY EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 32 - TASK 0 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 31 - TASK 1 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 29 - TASK 3 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 30 - TASK 2 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 28 - TASK 4 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 25 - TASK 7 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 26 - TASK 6 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 19 - TASK 8 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 27 - TASK 5 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 18 - TASK 9 EXIT
31.05.2018 15:06:00 - 33 - END
```

А та ошибка, что вы указываете - это да, это именно проблема, когда вы в процессе подсчета значения, прямо внутри вашей ресурсоемкой операции, пытаетесь рекурсивно это значение получить.

Воспроизвести очень просто.

```
Lazy<int> value = null;
value = new Lazy<int>(()=>value.Value); 
Console.WriteLine(value.Value);
```

на выходе будет исключение `ValueFactory пытается получить доступ к свойству Value этого экземпляра.`, так как невозможно посчитать, чем равно Value, если вы внутри этого подсчета пытаетесь его использовать.

Comment: Спасибо большое за наглядный пример. Рекурсивного обращения нет, но есть обращение из второго потока, и Lazy бросает исключение. Решается при помощи передачи в конструктор LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly. Подробнее о каждом режиме: [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: однако, не хотелось бы, что все потоки начинали инициализацию, поскольку инициализация всё же ресурсоёмкая.. Таким образом, пришли к вопросу о том, можно ли сделать Binding к свойствам синхронным?

Comment: @БадаловБадал я вам показал обращение из 10 потоков параллельно и это работает. И вы этот пример можете запустить и сами проверить. А вот вашего примера с ошибкой и без рекурсивных вызовов нету - потому по вашему коду что то сказать невозможно. Приведите [минмальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), тогда поглядим